# How can I use browser media to send it over RTMP push input into AWS media live

Tags: amazon-web-services, webrtc, rtmp, rtp, aws-media-live

We are using AWS media live for live streaming. In AWS media live have input channels which are RTP push,RTMP push, RTMP pull, HLS, MP4. Here we need to send the live media through browser webcam.
Please suggest how can we proceed for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant. It's not possible to push RTMP from the browser (Unless you use flash). You need to create an intermediary server that can take protocol the browser does support (like WebRTC, or web sockets) and convert that RTMP, then push from there.

Comment: Can you elaborate about what type of intermediary server here can we use?

Comment: Any media server - wowza, ant, flashphoner, kurento, unreal media server